# What's the 'proper' way to bind Vue state data to a database?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

At the moment, if a user causes an action that edits data, I send the API call off and then just effectively do a 'refresh' command to my app that re-downloads all the relevant data from the database, and the view updates accordingly.

Should I instead be directly editing data in my Vuex state, and have some sort of watcher function that observes those changes and writes them back to the DB?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't start by editing the data directly in Vuex as that may not then accurately represent the current state of your database, which could get very awkward...

Instead I would create an API module within your app that returns a Promise which makes the required updates to your database. Then on the success / error response coming from your database's API you resolve / reject the Promise. On success the resolve callback can pass the updated data.

Therefore on an edit the vue API is called, which sends the request and data to your database endpoint. The vue API returns a promise which you then chain to update your Vuex state. On success you receive an object containing the updated data, on error you get the message and alert the user if required, i.e.

```
# Your Vue API
setUserName: (username) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  // send request to your database, assuming via vue resource
  Vue.http.post('www.endpoint.com', { name: username })
    .then(responseData => resolve(responseData.name))
    .catch(errorData => reject(errorData))

}

# Your Vuex Action
updateUserName: ({ commit }) => {

  YourVueAPI.setUserName('joe')
    .then(name => commit('SET_USERNAME', name))
    .catch(errorData => alert(errorData.message))

}

# Your Vuex Mutation
SET_USERNAME: (state, name) {

  state.username = name

}
```

Something like the above will allow you to only show the updated username when it is correctly set within your database. Therefore ensuring the user is always aware of the correct state of the DB.

Vue will then allow you to easily react/watch the Vuex state to update your page.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I already do. Consider a list of 50 laptops in a table in VueJS - if the user performs a batch update to 20 of those laptops, currently, I send off the API call, and on a 200 response I then perform a new API call to get the list of 50 again, now with updated data. Doesn't feel particularly elegant or granular, but it keeps the amount of code down. Was just wondering what everyone else is doing.

Comment: To me the elegance comes from the Promises - a personal preference but I find them an amazing addition when it comes to complex chaining - avoiding the Pyramid of doom! If you were to change the action (updateUserName) to return a Promise then that may help you in terms of the feedback you can give your user. Calling the action within a component you can then set / unset a loading state based on its progress. Overall though the above should be pretty easy to follow. Vuex inherently adds complexity but I'm sure you already know how beneficial it can be.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement vuex actions which will trigger state change together with saving to database in background as actions are async.